# Chain Promises in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise, q, chain

This two functions are part of a controller of a music playlist project i'm working on. After the user selects his files , the prepare function is called to check if each file is valid to play. when done the getIDtags is called to add ID3tags data to each file.

```
       var preparePlaylist = function (files){

            var allPromises = [],
                currentSongsListLength = $scope.songsList.length || 0;

            $.each(files, function (index){                    
                var file = files[index];
                file.index = index + currentSongsListLength;
                var promiseA = FileValidator2.check(file);
                allPromises.push(promiseA);
                promiseA
                    .then (function (file){
                    SharedService.addSong(file.index, file);
                });
            });

           $q
                .all(allPromises)
                .then(function () {                        
                    console.log('Check Resolved!');
                    console.log('SharedService updated.');
                    getID3tags();
           });
        };


        var getID3tags = function (){
            var ID3tagsPromises = [];

            $.each($scope.songsList, function(index){
                var promiseB = ID3tags.getTags($scope.songsList[index]);
                ID3tagsPromises.push(promiseB);
                promiseB
                    .then( function (file){
                        SharedService.addSong(file.index, file);
                    });
            });

            $q
                .all(ID3tagsPromises)
                .then(function () {                        
                    console.log('ID3tags Resolved!');
                    console.log('SharedService updated.');                        
            });

        };
```

How to combine the 2 functions/promises(promiseA, promiseB) into one function with chained promise and still get $q.all when all is done.Thanxs.

Comment: sorry, but question is quite unclear

Answer (score 1):

So, each function in your file there is to be called one after the other (for this problem domain) then try this.

If functionA returns a promise and functionB returns a promise, functionA's promise can be resolved with the promise from functionB.

```
function preparePlaylist(){
    var finished = $q.defer();
    // rest of function body
    $q.all(allPromises).then(function(){
        //Do whatever you need
        finished.resolve(getID3tags());
    });
    return finished.promise;

function getID3tags(){
    var finished = $q.defer();
    //rest of function body
    $q.all(ID3tagsPromises).then(function(){
        //Do whatever you need
        finished.resolve('Done both preparePlaylist and getID3tags');
    });
    return finished.promise;

preparePlaylist.then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

This might need a little tweaking, but it should work. I've not tested it however. Hope it helps!

Docs for reference: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Comment: Hey ryaan thanxs but i think i've not explain my self correctly. The 2 function has exactly the same structure (syntax wise) .I would like to turn it into 1 func that has a chained promise. first it check the file, get resolved and then get the ID tag and gets resolved with only one $.each. hope i made my self a little more clear.